# Solving problem when the probability given itself is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Two scientists are conducting an experiement each, exactly once. Inducator X denotes the success of the experiment of the first scientist and Y is the same indicator for the other. The probability of a success is Z , where Z is a continous random variable distributed uniformly in [0,1]. 1.Find probability that X=1. 2. Are X and Y independent? Having a hard time with this one, thanks in advance!

Comment: What can be wrong with $P(X=1)=\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Z]]=\mathbb EZ=0.5$ then? Are you sure that $0.5$ is not correct?

Comment: Are there two independent copies of Z, one for each experiment, or a shared Z?

Comment: drhab i edited my post. Can you explain why the E(E(X|Z)) is E(Z)? And Mark Kortnik- its a shared Z yes.

Comment: It didnt really make sense to me either but it showed up on my exam last week unfortunately...just the way i wrote it down here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment we can find $\mathsf P(X=1)=\mathsf P(Y=1)$ by means of:$$\mathsf P(X=1)=\mathsf EX=\mathsf E[\mathsf E[X\mid Z]]=\mathsf EZ=0.5$$

Likewise we can find $\mathsf P(X=1\wedge Y=1)$ by means of: $$\mathsf P(X=1\wedge Y=1)=\mathsf EXY=\mathsf E[\mathsf E[XY\mid Z]]=\mathsf EZ^2=\int^1_0z^2dz=\frac13$$

So that: $$\mathsf P(X=1\wedge Y=1)=\frac13\neq\frac14=\frac12\frac12=\mathsf P(X=1)\mathsf P(Y=1)$$showing that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

---

For further explanation of equality $\mathsf EX=\mathsf E[\mathsf E[X\mid Z]]$ have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this equality. The only thing i dont really get is: why does  E(X|Z)=E(Z)..? By intiuition this makes sense,but how can i get there? Im having a hard time calculating this because Z is continous but X is discrete..Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: You could find $P(X=1)$ more directly on base of $P(X=1)=\int P(X=1\mid Z=z)f_Z(z)dz=\int_0^1P(X=1\mid Z=z)dz=\int_0^1zdz=0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have infinitely many coins, with the coin bias (i.e. probability of Heads) uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Two scientists randomly choose a coin; the first scientist tosses the coin, and then the second scientist tosses the same coin. Random variable $X$ is equal to $1$ if the first scientist got Heads, $0$ otherwise. Random variable $Y$ is like $X$, only for the second toss (by the second scientist, it does not really matter that the scientist is different).

Now it is getting clear that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent (because the same coin is tossed twice), and $P(X=1)$ is indeed $0.5$:
$$P(X=1)=\int_0^1zdz=\frac{1}{2}$$